# Как выводить новые записи в PostreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть база данных в Postgresql и в ней таблицы со столбцами.
Я хочу получать все новые данные если будет новая запись в базе данных. Как это можно реализовать? Я так понял в SELECT запросе можно сделать цикл или поставить условие если будет новые записи в таблице то пусть их выводит и ждет дальше новые записи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру хочу получать все новые записи в столбце coins

Идея пришла зделать так:
Чтобы получить новые записи, ты должен где-то хранить максимальное значение id или максимальное же значение times, полученные предыдущим запросом. И запрашивать только записи с id или times больше сохранённого значения.

Ты сам должен где-то и как-то обеспечить это хранение. Это только твоя обязанность - обеспечить выборку ровно тех данных, которые тебе нужны. Самой же базе данных глубоко фиолетово, что там было добавлено после последнего запроса на выборку.

Можешь, например, сделать отдельную таблицу, в которою записывать максимальный id последнего запроса.

Comment: Для начала сформулируй у себя в голове что такое "новая запись". И нет, нельзя никаких циклов делать в SQL-запросе.

Comment: *Как это можно реализовать?* Добавить поле последней корректировки записи и обновлять его из триггера.

Comment: Добавил такую идею реализации данной задачи